# C# copying or accessing two dimensional array from child form

Tags: c#, forms, parent-child, multidimensional-array

I have created two forms in the designer, formA and formB, one is a default parent form and the latter is a modified "about box". I need to know the best way to get data of a two dimensional array to formB from formA, but so far I've only got it to "work" when formA was inadvertently opened a second time alongside formB.

Basic code at the moment is:

```
// Form A (onload)
public string[,] arrayname = new string[5, 2] { some values };
// Form A (onevent)
formB f2 = new formB(arrayname);
f2.Show();

// Form B (onload)
???
label1.Text = arrayname[0, 0];
label2.Text = arrayname[0, 1];
label3.Text = arrayname[1, 0];
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way for me is to change the child form (FormB) constructor to accept an array of String as parameter :

```
private string[,] arrayname;
public FormB(string[,] _arrayname)
{
this.arrayname = _arrayname;
}
```

and when you create your instance of FormB :

```
formB f2 = new formB(arrayname);
f2.Show();
```

Comment: +1 This is probably how I would design it. Additionally, I'd make the default constructor private to communicate `arrayName` needs values for the form to be useful. `private FormB(){}`

Answer (score 1):

make a public property on `FormB`

```
public string [,] SomeArray {get;set;}
```

Then set it when you display

```
FormB f = new FormB();
f.SomeArray = this.arrayname;
f.Show();
```

Then in FormB

```
this.label1.Text = this.SomeArray[0,0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest would be to expose it as a property in `FormB` like so:

```
public string[,] Hours { get; set; }
```

And set it right after you create the instance:

```
FormB myFormB = new FormB();
myFormB.ArrayName = new string[5, 2] { some values };
```

Comment: This seemed to parse an error?

'WindowsFormsApplication1.FormB' does not contain a definition for 'arrayname' and no extension method 'arrayname' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.FormB' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Edited my answer. You need to create a property for `FormB` first.